# How to rebuild/restart kerberos server on Mac 10.6.5 Server

Tags: ldap, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

I had DNS trouble which was causing delays for Open Directory users logging in from the GUI on their macs.

I've fixed the DNS problems and the delay still remains.

Is there a way to restart, or start/stop, the Open Directory service (or just the Kerberos part) without restarting the server?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to check status of your OD using changeip command.

```
$ sudo changeip -checkhostname
```

If it reports any problem, backup your OD using Server Admin and follow the result from the command above

Answer (score 2):

To stop/start Open Directory:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist
```

To stop/start Kerberos:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.mit.Kerberos.kadmind.plist
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.mit.Kerberos.krb5kdc.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.mit.Kerberos.kadmind.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.mit.Kerberos.krb5kdc.plist
```

Note these are 10.6.x specific commands. They're slightly different for versions above and below.

Comment: I get "No such file or directory" in 10.13 :-(

Comment: Yeah, this process isn't supported on current versions (as per the the last line in my post). You can use "serveradmin stop/start dirserv" if you want to stop/start OD. Unsure about Kerberos in 10.13.